# Linear CABasicAnimation isn't executed linearly in Container View

Tags: swift, animation, cabasicanimation

Even after setting the timingFunction explicitly to *linear* to animation is not executed linearly.

I use the following code to initialize the animation.

*Further down is the implementation of the whole class and how the ViewController is set up in the InterfaceBuilder*

```
private func timeLayerAnimation() {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation()
    animation.keyPath = "strokeEnd"
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.duration = 240.0
    animation.toValue = 0
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    timeLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

The view looks like the following.
[image]

The total animation duration is 240 seconds.

But after 30 sec. already only 75 % of the circle remain visible.

The stopped times are as follows:

```
75 % (1.5 π):    30  sec. (∆ 30 sec.)

50 % (1 π):      70  sec. (∆ 40 sec.)

25 % (0.5 π):    120 sec. (∆ 50 sec.)

// 13 % (0.25 π):   155 sec.

0  % (0 π):      240 sec. (∆ 120 sec.)
```

**Update**

I found that the problem occurs when the ViewController responsible for the animation lives inside a container view.

My guess is that it could have something to do with the default *UIViewAnimationCurve*, but I'm not sure and I don't know how where to start to test that :(

[image]

**All sides of the Container View are pinned to the safe area.
The Implementation of the MainVC is empty and the EmbeddedVC looks as follows:**

```
import UIKit


class EmbeddedVC: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - Properties

    let timeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        setupTimerLayout()
    }

}

// MARK: - Timer Layout Setup
extension EmbeddedVC {

    func setupTimerLayout() {
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: .zero,
                                             radius: view.frame.width * 0.36,
                                             startAngle: 0,
                                             endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi,
                                             clockwise: true)

        // Configure time layer
        timeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        timeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        timeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        timeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        timeLayer.strokeEnd = 1
        timeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        timeLayer.position = view.center

        view.layer.addSublayer(timeLayer)
        animateTimeLayer()
    }


    private func animateTimeLayer() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation()
        animation.keyPath = "strokeEnd"
        animation.duration = 240.0
        animation.toValue = 0
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        timeLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
I thought it maybe had something to do with a typical beginners mistake.
I will try to find the hunt down the mistake / make a MCVE.

Comment: @Rob I updated the answer and added kind of a MCVE. As stated in the updated answer the problem occurs when the ViewController is embedded in an container view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be called multiple times and you are not specifying `fromValue` so these two animations are interfering with each other. You can solve this any combination of the below:

1. Add a check to see if you started the animation already:

   ```
   var hasStarted = false

   private func startAnimation() {            
       guard !hasStarted else { return }

       hasStarted = true

       ...
   }
   ```

   (Note, I'd suggest you always call `super` when overriding these methods.)
2. Remove the animation before starting another animation.
3. Specify a `fromValue` in your animation:

   ```
   private func startAnimation() {
       let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
       animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
       animation.duration = ...
       animation.fromValue = 1  // by setting this, it won't get confused if you start the animation again
       animation.toValue = 0
       ...

       shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
   }
   ```
4. Defer this until `viewDidAppear`:

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)

       // start your animation here
   }
   ```

Personally, I'd do both #3 and #4, but you can do whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

*@Rob thanks a lot for your answer this one really drove me crazy... :)*

Everything works perfect now. I just want to add something to #1 for people who work with extensions and don't want to use a local variable on the base class or can't access the base class.

```
private func animateTimeLayer() {
    let animationKey = "animateTimeLayerKey"

    guard nil == timeLayer.animation(forKey: animationKey) else { return }

    let animation = CABasicAnimation()

    ...

    timeLayer.add(animation, forKey: animationKey)
}
```